# Stack to save position

Tags: python, stack, position

I'm developing a spell checker for a Peruvian language in Python.

The case is that I have the wrong word "tponti" when the real word is "tsonti". My idea is to go over the word and try to form different possible options.

For example:

When you are at the "p" position and check that the letter before it is "t", there is a mistake so the options are:

- delete "p"
- change "p" by vocal
- change positions between "p" and "o".

I was trying to use a stack to save the position, the type of path to follow (-1 to delete, 0 to change with vocals, 1 to change positions) and the formed word. Because I get to the last position in the word I can return to the last saved position and follow another path.
If you need the real code:

Enter to get pgrafo.py in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9TJF4xuMuwdVXdwcFFnT0J1aTg/view?usp=sharing it's in gdrive.
Enter to get grafo2.xlsx in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9TJF4xuMuwddmtvSEp1MENGNEk/view?usp=sharing it's in gdrive.

```
enter code here
word = "tponti"
pos = 0
formed = ""
typoe = -1
stackPos = []
stackFormed = []
stackType = []
while(pos < len(word)):
    formed = formed + word[pos]
    if detecError(formed[-1],word[pos]):
        if type == -1:
            stackPos.append(pos)
            stackFormed.append(formed)
            stackType(0)
        if type == 0:
            #changeLetters
            stackPos.append(pos)
            stackFormed.append(formed)
            stackType(1)
        if type == 1:
            stackPos.append(pos)
            stackFormed.append(formed)
            stackType(-1) #to star in -1 in case there's a mistake later
        if pos == len(word) and len(stackPos) > 0:
            savePosibleFormed(formed)
            pos= stackPos.pop()
            formed= stackFormed.pop()
            type = stackType.pop()
            pos -= 1
    pos += 1
```

Comment: it gives me a infinite cycle.

Comment: Please show the debugging trace -- at least output from strategically-placed **print** statements.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: I add the link to my code if you like to try it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you do this with a recursive routine: let the run-time system maintain your stack.  Treat this as a search through a directed graph, looking for the least-cost path to a solution (i.e. Dijkstra's algorithm).  Each change is an edge, a movement from one graph node (spelling) to another.

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: it gives me a infinite cycle.

Comment: Does this comment refer to your implementation of my suggestion, or to the original question?  If it's to the original question, then please delete this comment.

Comment: I add the link to my code if you like to try it. I try to use the Dijkstra before, but I need all the posible of words.